# About Java security issues

Tags: discussion, support, javascript

Having heard about Java security issues I deactivated javascript in my firefox. Perhaps it is not javascript which is concerned, and I over-reacted. Anyhow, currently I have this permanent red banner `TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange works best with JavaScript enabled` for which no `closing button` is available (ironically perhaps because javascript is disabled? I don't know much about html and the like) and my questions is: *which features of TeX LaTeX Stack Exchange* am I losing with `javascript` disabled in my browser?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are entirely separate languages which just happen to share a common partial name. There are reasons some people disable JavaScript, but Java security is not one of them.

Comment: @JosephWright I had to reactivate javascript to access my inbox and I feel the stress now about being at risk ;-) ok, so JavaScript has nothing to do with Java, and the current security issues about the latter have no incidence on the former, I am paraphrasing your comment just to feel safer ...

Comment: Also, Oracle has already released a new Java version.

Comment: +1 for asking and caring about your computer security – there’s always something new to learn.

Comment: Recent Java @ [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: @Speravir: There are apparently already known exploits for that version too.

Comment: @Caramdir Can you link to information about that?

Comment: @marczellm: http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/01/critical-java-vulnerabilies-confirmed-in-latest-version/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need to worry: Java and Javscript are entirely different things. To quote an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java):

> Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar.

The reason you can't close that permanent red banner is that without Javascript only static (non interactive) content can be served. Without Javascript you're missing out on quite a lot.

Comment: I never went beyond using simple `css` specifications... so I know javascript only as an end-user (unwilling) and my experience is that it is acceptable only in my firefox with pop-ups set to unauthorized and AdBlockPlus. But it might not be that great Evil I was fearing...

Comment: Great comparison! `:D`

Comment: This answer addresses the OPs concerns but it does not answer the question “which features of TeX LaTeX Stack Exchange am I losing with javascript disabled?”

Answer (score 17):

Javascript takes care of everything that is *happening* (changing, moving) on a site. Such as

- timestamps of posts refreshing themselves every minute
- clicking a link or an image to bring up a box, like the question mark above the answer editing area to bring up Help
- live preview of question/answer as you edit
- notifications that a new question was asked or the current one was edited
- everything about Inbox
- hovering over a tag to display the description

etc.

Comment: I was indeed asking for such a list in my question, thanks.